# display an object's attributes in python

Tags: python, oop, list

I would like to display the attributes of a give object and was wondering if there was a python function for it.
For example if I had an object from the following class:

```
class Antibody():

    def __init__(self,toSend):

        self.raw = toSend
        self.pdbcode = ''
        self.year = ''
```

Could I get an output that looks something like this or something similar:

```
['self.raw','self.pdbcode','self.year']
```

thanks

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The following method prints `['self.pdbcode', 'self.raw', 'self.year']` for an instance of your class:

```
class Antibody():
    ...
    def get_fields(self):
        ret = []
        for nm in dir(self):
           if not nm.startswith('__') and not callable(getattr(self, nm)):
              ret.append('self.' + nm)
        return ret

a = Antibody(0)
print a.get_fields()
```

Comment: thanks a lot this is just what I need. Thanks for the full explanation

Answer (score 15):

Try `dir(self)`.  It will include all attributes, not only "data".

Answer (score 1):

Like this

```
class Antibody:
    def __init__(self,toSend):
        self.raw = toSend
        self.pdbcode = ''
        self.year = ''
    def attributes( self ):
        return [ 'self.'+name for name in self.__dict__ ]
```

Comment: Thanks I'm voting this up as well for brevity!

Answer (score 0):

`a = Antibody(0)`

`map(lambda attr: 'self.%s'%(attr), filter(lambda attr: not callable(getattr(a, attr)), a.__dict__))`